# Can someone explain this wildcard gsub code, particularly the "\\1" part

Tags: r, regex, gsub

If I have the following character vectors:

```
names(x)
[1] "EMM88 emm88.0 (emm-cluster E4)"   "EMM225 emm225.0 (emm-cluster D4)"
[3] "EMM52 emm52.0 (emm-cluster D4)"   "EMM2 emm2.0 (emm-cluster E4)"    
[5] "EMM114 emm114.0 (emm-cluster E4)"
```

And I want to just keep the "EMM?" portion including the number (e.g. "EMM88" in the case of "EMM88 emm88.0 (emm-cluster E4)"), I can use the following code:

```
names(x) <- gsub("(.*?) .*", "\\1", names(x))
```

And gives the desired output:

```
names(x)
[1] "EMM88"  "EMM225" "EMM52"  "EMM2"   "EMM114"
```

I have read the documentation of "gsub" and a few other questions but am still struggling to understand how the code leads to the desired outcome.

I understand the first argument (`"(.*?) .*", "\\1"`) is the pattern to look for in the second argument (`names(x)`).

I don't understand the `(.*?)`,

the `.*` means any number of characters, so what does combining them into `(.*?) .*` mean?

And what does adding on the `"\\1"` do?

As you can see I am missing some fundamentals of "wildcard" and "gsub" coding knowledge, any help much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this and needs some support using regex, I found this site very useful: https://regex101.com. It allows you to test your regex on your own string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.*?` tries to stop at every character in the string but the regex engine wants to report an overall match and needs to match the whitespace after the first capture group as well, so it tries to stop at every character until it eventually reaches the first whitespace. All characters up to this point are stored in the first capture group - referred to as `\\1` in the replacement part.
The rest of the expression consumes the rest of the string and the string is replaced only with the first capture group.

In general, the dot star is "expensive" (the engine tries to stop at every character) and should be avoided if possible.

---

That said, you could use the more effective

```
names(x) <- gsub("([^ ]+).*", "\\1", names(x))
```

instead. This captures anything not a whitespace in the first group and is likely to come to an end faster.

Comment: Thanks @Jan, I am new to this , could you please clarify exactly what part of the original code or suggested code is saying "stop at first whitespace".

i.e. does the '.*' inherently mean "any number of characters, until whitespace". Or in your suggested example how does '([^ ]+).*' refer to "not whitespace"? The rest makes sense now.

Comment: @reubenmcg: Please have some reading on regular expressions as this is a broad field. `[^ ]+` means: *not a whitespace*, as many as possible. [**regexone.com**](https://regexone.com) is a good starting place.

Comment: thanks for the resource. I agree I need some general regex reading.